# Find the domain and range of a function that assigns to a bit string the number of bits in the string.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I'm learning about functions and ranges, and I'm confused with how to answer the above. I'm thinking the domain should be all bit strings except the empty string (string with no bits), and the range should be $Z^+$?

Or should the range be 0,1?

Comment: Why not the empty string?  Function value is $0$.  Except for this (and the corresponding adjustment in the range) your first thought is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain is all bit strings.
The range is all non-negative integers.